# How do i get request parameter in transformresponse

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Based on request parameter i wish to modify the response in transformresponse. So how do get request parameter(query string) in transformresponse

```
        return $resource(apiPath, {
            rest: 1,
            fv: 2,
            type: @type
        }, {
                query: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    isArray:true,
                    url: config.apiBaseUrl + 'poll/list',
                    transformResponse: function(data, headers) {
                        var json_data = JSON.parse(data);
                        return json_data;
                        //get type parameter here
                    }
                },
            }
```

Comment: `document.location.search`